# AFNetworking detect when wifi connection without active internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` and was wondering how to detect a scenario when user is connected to a wifi network without active internet connection.

I reproduce this scenario buy powering a router without connecting the dsl line.

```
AFNetworking return  AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi = 2
```

my code:

```
 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
        self.isInternetAvialable = status > 0;
    }];
```

thanks

I refacotred the code to be like

```
  AFNetworkReachabilityManager* manager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"http://www.google.com"];
        [manager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
            NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
            self.isInternetAvialable = status > 0;
        }];
        [manager startMonitoring];
```

now the block never get called!

Comment: did the accepted answer worked for you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]` which just monitors network connectivity, you can use `[AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:(NSString *)domain]` and pass an appropriate hostname - such as "www.google.com" - this way you can test whether the network you are connected to has Internet access - it can still be fooled by local DNS and a web server, but I would think that it is unlikely someone would do that.

Once you have your `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` you can set the change block as you do for the shared manager

Comment: How long did you wait?  It could take quite a while to fail due to DNS timeout.  You could also try a well known host such as 8.8.8.8 to avoid DNS lookup

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Reachability**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class and its `reachabilityForInternetConnection` method.

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];   
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];    

if (networkStatus == NotReachable) 
{        
    NSLog(@"There is NO Internet connection");        
} 
else 
{        
     NSLog(@"There is Internet connection");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class by Apple. It has all the functions you need. Your best bet here is to use a domain (like Google) to check for actual internet connectivity.

Summarised sample code:

Add observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];

internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];

[internetReachable startNotifier];

// check if a pathway to a random host exists

hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"SOME_HOST"];

[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

Then, in the target method:

```
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice {

NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

switch (internetStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");

        break;
    }
}

NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

switch (hostStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Apple's Reachability doesn't actually tell you if it can connect to a host, only if it _could_ connect to one.  As per their note: `Note: Reachability cannot tell your application if you can connect to a particular host, only that an interface is available that might allow a connection, and whether that interface is the WWAN.`  You can test this by disconnecting the internet from your WiFi router.  Reachability will still say Google is reachable as long as the device is connected to WiFi.